# Empty PHP Logs when using Sentry

Tags: php, exception, sentry

I'm using Sentry to log all errors received in my PHP application. So, high up in my application boostrap, I have the following

```
$raven_client = new Raven_Client('long_string_no_really_long');
$error_handler = new Raven_ErrorHandler($raven_client);
$error_handler->registerExceptionHandler();
$error_handler->registerErrorHandler();
$error_handler->registerShutdownFunction();
```

Then for testing purposes I throw the following immediately after:

```
throw new Exception("Hello");
```

The Sentry logging itself is fine and the logs are piped to our hosted dashboard. However, our actual PHP log is empty (where it used to be writing exceptions) and I'd really like the errors to also be handled by PHP and written to the php error log.

This is useful, for example, if the Sentry server is unavailable - I don't want the messages to disappear into a virtual /dev/null.

I've been trying to play with the register functions but nothing seems to indicate I can rethrow the error so that PHP can handle it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Mind opening any issue on the raven-php GitHub tracker? It sounds like this might be a bug (it should call the default error handler).

Comment: Sure. Will do. Was hoping I was just misunderstanding something. I've checked around the function definitions. Nothing seems to be out of place. Anyway, off to log an issue.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, but when using the Monolog handler. Have you find a solution? If so, please share. Maybe it's useful for me and others.